# Basic selection sort code

Tags: c++

I'm a super noob at c++. For some reason this sorting code wont work, any help would be great thanks!
The method i'm attempting to use is selection sort.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int nTotalSize = 5;
    int data[nTotalSize] = { 7, 47, 1, 8, 2 };
    for (int iii = 0; iii < 5; iii++)
    {
        int nCurrentSmall = iii;
        for (int jjj = iii+1; jjj < nTotalSize; jjj++)
        {
            if (data[jjj] < data[iii])
            {
                nCurrentSmall = jjj;
            }
        }
        swap(data[iii], data[nCurrentSmall]);
    }
    for (int iii = 0; iii < 5; iii++)
    {
        cout << data[iii] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? What issues are you facing?

Comment: The code will compile but it produces the output of 2,7,1,8,47. Apologies for lack of details.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried debugging it at all? How about something simple like printing the value of `data[iii]` after the `swap` and checking if it matches expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some simple modifications...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  const int nTotalSize = 5;
  int data[nTotalSize] = { 7, 47, 1, 8, 2 };
  for (int iii = 0; iii < nTotalSize-1; iii++)
    {
      int nCurrentSmall = iii;
      for (int jjj = iii+1; jjj < nTotalSize; jjj++)
        {
      if (data[jjj] < data[nCurrentSmall])
            {
          nCurrentSmall = jjj;
            }
        }
      swap(data[iii], data[nCurrentSmall]);
    }
  for (int iii = 0; iii < 5; iii++)
    {
      cout << data[iii] << endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: when looking for the smallest element, you need to be comparing against the smallest value seen so far. You are comparing against something else.

Answer (score 1):

You defined:

```
int nCurrentSmall = iii;
```

but you didn't use it as it should be used in selection sort.

```
        if (data[jjj] < data[iii])
        {
            nCurrentSmall = jjj;
        }
```

This is used to compare indexes of data[iii] to every element data[jjj] and change the index of iii with the index of the current item when the element is smaller than the current item, but since you're comparing data[iii] the whole time, it's not working because the value getting changed is nCurrentSmall, and the value of nCurrentSmall should also be the value of iii as well to reflect the changes. Change it to this:

```
        if (data[jjj] < data[nCurrentSmall])
        {
            nCurrentSmall = jjj;
        }
```